# Possible to "seed" a comparison function for use with sorted(...)

Tags: python, sorting

**EDIT**

It would seem that my original question was flawed; I was confusing `key` with `cmp` as indicated by KillianDS and jonrsharpe. Using `cpm` with my class callable worked as expected.

I've accepted jonrsharpe's answer as it's a more correct answer to "how to seed a function with data".

**Original Question**

Is is possible to pre-seed a function with data before passing it for use with Python's `sorted(list, key=comp)` function?

I've tried creating a class callable, like so:

```
class MyComp(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __call__(self, a, b):
        # compares `a` with `b`, optionally using `data`


sortfunc = MyComp(True)
sorted(mylist, key=sortfunc)
```

However, when I try this I get a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I've also tried with a wrapped function:

```
def my_comp(data):
    def comp(a, b):
        ...
    return comp


sortfunc = my_comp(True)
sorted(mylist, key=sortfunc)
```

But this also fails with a `TypeError`, although differently:

```
TypeError: comp() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Is there any way I can achieve the result I'm looking for?

Comment: "pre-seed a function with data" Why? What do you mean?

Comment: you're confusing `cmp` and `key`, is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: @Tichodroma There's some information I need to use for the comparison between `a` and `b` that's not available as either `a` or `b`... a kind of "weighted" sort where I need to specify the weight dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general case, to define some of the arguments to be passed to a function when it's called, you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def f(x, y):
    return x + y

>>> g = partial(f, y=2)
>>> g(3) # x=3, y=2
5
```

In this case, bear in mind that the `key` for `sorted` is only called with a single argument - a value is generated for each item in `mylist` using the `key`, then the list is sorted based on those values. It isn't called with pairs of items; that's `cmp` (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)).